# Select into tables in SQL. How are they stored?

Tags: sql, postgresql, session, temp-tables

When I run a script in PostgreSQL I usually do the following from `psql`:

```
my_database> \i my_script.sql
```

Where in `my_script.sql` I may have code like the following:

```
select a.run_uid, s.object_uid into temp_table from dt.table_run_group as a 
inner join dt.table_segment as s on a.group_uid = s.object_uid;
```

In this particular case, I am only interested in creating `temp_table` with the results of the query.

Are these results in disk on the server? In memory? Is the table stored permanently?

Comment: The query in the form you have shown (with `into temp_table` part) should store the whole output of the query into the table `temp_table ` and it wont output the results to `psql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Temporary tables are stored in RAM until the available memory is used up, at which time they spill onto disk. The relevant setting here is [`temp_buffers`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-TEMP-BUFFERS).
- Either way, they live for the duration of a *session* and are dropped at the end automatically.
- You can also drop them at the end of a *transaction* automatically ([`ON COMMIT DROP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)) or manually any time.
- Temporary table are only visible to the the same user in the same session. Others cannot access it - and also not conflict with it.
- Always use `CREATE TABLE tbl AS ...`. The alternative form `SELECT ... INTO tbl` is discouraged since it conflicts with the `INTO` clause in plpgsql.

Your query could look like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl AS
SELECT a.run_uid, s.object_uid
FROM   dt.table_run_group a 
JOIN   dt.table_segment   s ON a.group_uid = s.object_uid;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT INTO table ...` is the same as `CREATE TABLE table AS ...`, which creates a normal, permanent table.

Comment: Great. Thanks! Is there any way to create a temporary table so that it is destroyed when I disconnect? And would such tables be stored as regular tables in the database?